# Multireader with document count > 2.1billion

Tags: java, lucene

I have a document count that is greater than 2.1 billion. I am choosing to split my index into multiple indicies by month.

Now I need to search the entire index (across all months...)

One thing I am reading is that I can use a `MultiReader` to combine multiple `IndexReader` instances. But given that it will return a document number in the range of `0 < x < Integer.MAX_VALUE` (or thereabouts), what if the search returns more than 2.1 billion results?

Is my only way to search each index in isolation?

**EDIT with extra information:**

I need to process every document. I am not using scoring. I believe the terminology is that I am using the "inverted index" feature.

I am using Lucene 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

What are you planning on doing with the results? If this is for end-user consumption, an appropriate way of doing this would be to return the top N (10? 100?) from each index, and then merge them together based on score and show the user the top results across all indexes.

If you're planning on processing all of these somehow you can return them in batches and process each accordingly.

Comment: Process each result, I am not using scoring. I believe the terminology is that I am using the "inverted index" feature.

Comment: Please update your question with all this information since this is highly relevant to the answer. Also let us know what version.